# jquery not seeing new html loaded into dialogue box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having some trouble with getting jquery to recognize classes/ids of content that has been loaded into a dialogue box. All the jquery code (including the code that deals with the as yet unloaded classes) is loaded before the dialogue box is created, however the html that eventually goes into the dialogue box is created on the fly. I know it is going to get certain classes but don't know the rest of the code/content hence the reason I am loading it from the database. If I put the html on the page with the clickable class rather than the dialogue box it works, but I obviously don't want to do that. I was thinking this is a DOM problem since the class that jquery is going to be listening for is not on the page until AFTER the dialogue box is created (the dialogue box itself is also created by a click on another item - this has to happen this way as people may or may not want to get the dialogue box with the info from the database in it up). Any help in explaining and possibly finding a solution for this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [jQuery.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Comment: I know it was vague but I guess someone else understood my blithering.